# Styling one div affects another div unintentionally

Tags: css, reactjs

When I change paddings of the left-center-box div, it also affects the right-center-box in the same way. I don't know why the right-center-box is affected and why the left and right center boxes are not aligned. This is how it looks now. How can I align them horizontally and then style only the left-center-box div?

[image]

HomeMain.js

```
export class HomeMain extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="main-box">
          <div className="left-main-box"></div>
          <div className="right-main-box"></div>
          <CenterBox />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

CenterBox.js

```
export class CenterBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-center-box">
        <div className="left-center-box">
          <img src={TestImg} alt="Profile picture"></img>
          <h2>Name</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="right-center-box">ugghghg</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.scss

```
/* Homepage Style */

.main-box {
  height: $main-container-height;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  .left-main-box {
    height: $main-container-height;
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ede7dd;
  }

  .right-main-box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: $main-container-height;
    width: 55%;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

// Homepage center box style

.main-center-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  top: calc(70% - 800px / 2);
  left: calc(50% - 800px / 2);
  text-align: center;

  .left-center-box {
    background-color: #faf7f4;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 550px;
    padding: 40px 40px 0 40px;
    img {
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 190px;
      width: 190px;
    }

    h2 {
      margin-top: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
  .right-center-box {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 550px;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are so many resources on what you're asking. I think it's good you're attempting to go about it the very old-fashioned way, because you're going to learn a lot from the experience judging by the looks of things. I would suggest you do some more research. Once you get the hang of the CSS properties `margin`, `display` and `position` you could maybe move on to Grid Systems of the likes of Flexbox or Bootstrap.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Thanks for the advice.